# ¿Como puedo separa un String obtenido de un Codigo QR y mostrarlo en diferentes EditText?

Tags: android-studio

me estoy iniciando en el mundo de Android Studio a la cual estoy haciendo una APP que me permita escanear el codigo Qr, donde se obtiene el siguiente dato de Ejmplo: **ID289/HP/G15/HPXCVB123/123/IRVING CRUZ**, una vez obtenido este se almacene en diferentes EditText, Ejmplo: txtqr, txtmarca, txtmodelo, txtns, txtidpersonal, txtnombre. Hasta el momento solo he podido almacenarlo en un EditTex con id = txtqr, en el diseño ya tengo los EditTex mencionados, alguna sugerencia acepto todo tipo retroalimentacion, consejos, ejemplos para realizalo con un Split.

Este es mi codigo de mi MainActivity:

package com.example.lectorbarrayqr;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText codigo;
Button scanear;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    private ZXingScannerView vistascaner; //Iniciado el Scaner de Codigo de Barra yQR
    public void Escanear (View view){
        vistascaner = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        vistascaner.setResultHandler(new zxingscanner());
        setContentView(vistascaner);
        vistascaner.startCamera();
    }
    class zxingscanner implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{
        @Override
        public void handleResult(Result result){
            String dato=result.getText();
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            vistascaner.stopCamera();
            codigo=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtqr);
            codigo.setText(dato);
        }
    }//Finaliza el Lector de Codigos de barras y Qr
}
```

Comment: ¿Y qué problema tuviste al intentar separarlo con Split?

Comment: Un Splitazo y sale fácil

Answer (score 1):

Puedes separarlo con split te dejo un ejemplo

```
String dato;
String[] parts = dato.split("/");
String val1 = parts[0]; //Primer valor
String val2 = parts[1]; //Segundo valor
String val3 = parts[2]; //Tercer valor
 ...
```

Espero pueda servirte de algo